# Using LINQ, get all the objects from a list with a specific column value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

If I've got a List with several A's and properties, how can I with LINQ get all the A's in the list that got a property value of A.abc = "ABC". I want this to happen when the  SelectedIndexChanged is triggered of a dropdown list. I've tried the following:

```
var datasource = from A in GetListOfAs() where A.attribute == "ABC" select A;

            GridView1.DataSource = datasource;
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

And in my GridView I've got the following BoundFields:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="attribute" HeaderText="h1" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="df2" HeaderText="h2" />
```

So I want it to display like:

```
  h1             h2
  ------------------
  ABC            123
  ABC            456
```

EDIT:

The initial data source is the entire GetListOfAs(). I'm trying to list only the ones that have the value of attribute as "ABC", but it keeps showing the same list when I'm selecting ABC in the drop down list (I can see that the SelectedIndexChanged occurs, since the page reloads).

Page_Load method:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = GetListOfAs();
        GridView1.DataBind();

        ddl.DataSource = GetListOfChoices();
        ddl.DataTextField = "name";
        ddl.DataValueField = "attribute";
        ddl.DataBind();

        if (ddl.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            ddl.Items.Insert(0, "Select one");
            ddl.Items[0].Value = "";
            ddl.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
```

Apparently, the problem lies with not getting the correct SelectedValue.

I've got: `String ddlValue = ddl.SelectedValue;` Shouldn't that be working? I keep getting blank ("") which is the initial value.

Comment: It's still not clear what you're asking. You've got code that's already filtering by the property equal to `ABC`.

Comment: If you could, please post your code for the intial binding of the DataGrid (this is most likely the `Page_Load` event).  Please include the entire `Page_Load`

Comment: Are you sure you get the right value from the DropDownList in the SelectedIndexChanged event? Are you re-filling the DropDownList without checking IsPostBack?

Comment: @roryWoods You're right. I just checked and the value from the dropdownlist is wrong. I keep getting the initial value (which is just "").

Comment: Are you rebinding the dropdownlist on PostBack because you disabled ViewState? If so, rebind in Page_Init() so the selected value can be set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is add an `IsPostBack` check to your initial binding code inside of the `Page_Load` event.  `Page_Load` fires on every single postback, so if you don't do this check, you will effectively run your initial databinding (which includes all elements) every time.

Change your page load to this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // Only bind your gridview with all items, if this is the first page load
    if(!Page.IsPostBack) {
        GridView1.DataSource = GetListOfAs();
        GridView1.DataBind();

        ddl.DataSource = GetListOfChoices();
        ddl.DataTextField = "name";
        ddl.DataValueField = "attribute";
        ddl.DataBind();

        if (ddl.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            ddl.Items.Insert(0, "Select one");
            ddl.Items[0].Value = "";
            ddl.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }    

}
```

I think the `IsPostBack` binding mistake is made by every single ASP.net developer when they first start out, so don't feel bad!  You're in good company :).

Answer (score 0):

```
var datasource = GetListOfAs().Where(x=>x.attribute=="ABC").ToList();
```

That's another way to get what you already get with you way.